# How to add Gutenberg editor on frontend page?

Tags: block-editor, wp-enqueue-script

I have a textarea on a public-facing page. I want to add Gutenberg editor to that textarea. I searched the official documentation but couldn't find anything. Any information will be helpful.

Comment: This question is not clear; what textarea you have? Surely you do not mean HTML form element `textarea`. Is this text chunk of a theme? This question might be theme-dependent.

Comment: i want to use gutenberg editor on a frontend page. suppose I have created a page and published it. Now i want o use gutenber block editor on that page. Is it possible?

Comment: Gutenberg editor is by default active on all pages. You might have installed something that supresses gutenberg editor, try disabling your plugins.